# Testing class for variables inside a 'for' loop

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I need help writing the testing class for the code below. I am getting 68% test coverage. all the code inside the for loop is not getting any coverage. I will appreciate any help.

This is what I have so far:

class

```
 public class  ReworkOrderContr {
  public ReworkOrderContr ()     
  {      
  objectID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');


rework =[select Name,Location__c,Status__c, Work_Order_Date__c,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,Instructions__c,Processed_By__c,Start_Time__c,End_Time__c,Proc_Comments__c from Rework_Order__c where id  = : objectID ];
     for(Rework_Order__c rw :rework){
         name =rw.Name;
         location =rw.Location__c;
         status = rw.Status__c;
         processDate = rw.Work_Order_Date__c;
         createdBy=rw.CreatedBy.Name;
         createdDate=date.valueof(rw.CreatedDate);
         instructions=rw.Instructions__c;
         processedBy=rw.Processed_By__c;
         startDate =rw.Start_Time__c;
         endDate=rw.End_Time__c;
         procComments=rw.Proc_Comments__c;
     }
}
```

test class:

```
  @istest
 public class test_ReworkOrderContr {

 public static testmethod void testReworkOrderContr () {


 Account account = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Buyer__c='carlos',    Buyer_Email__c='carlos@netrush.com');
    insert account;

  NRProducts__c product = new NRProducts__c(Account__c = account.Id, Name = '105823437', Product_Name__c='105823437' );
   insert product;

   Rework_Order__c rw = new Rework_Order__c(Instructions__c='all  good',Work_Order_Date__c=date.newInstance(1960, 2, 17),Location__c='A5',Processed_By__c='carlos',Start_Time__c=DateTime.newInstanceGMT(2012,04,30,12,59,59),End_Time__c=DateTime.newInstanceGMT(2012,04,30,12,59,59),Proc_Comments__c='all good',Status__c='open');
   insert rw;


    ROD__c rod = new    ROD__c(Rework_Order__c=rw.id,NRProducts__c=product.id,Qty_Ordered__c=25,Qty_Built__c=25);
    insert rod;


  PageReference tpageRef = Page.ReworkOrder;
  Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);

   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id','rw.id' );
   System.assertEquals('rw.id',ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));

  ReworkOrderContr pcp = new ReworkOrderContr();

         pcp.name =rw.id;
         pcp.location =rw.Location__c;
         pcp.status = rw.Status__c;
         pcp.processDate = rw.Work_Order_Date__c;
         pcp.createdBy=rw.CreatedBy.Name;
         pcp.createdDate=date.valueof(rw.CreatedDate);
         pcp.instructions=rw.Instructions__c;
         pcp.processedBy=rw.Processed_By__c;
         pcp.startDate =rw.Start_Time__c;
         pcp.endDate=rw.End_Time__c;
         pcp.procComments=rw.Proc_Comments__c;*/

      //assert for all the variables
         System.assertEquals(rw.id__c,pcp.Name); 
         System.assertEquals(rw.Location__c,pcp.location);
         ....etc

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'rw.id'` in your test method should be `rw.id` (no quotes). Since the query doesn't pull back any records, because you're literally querying for the string "rw.id" instead of the 18-character ID, the loop never executes once.

Comment: sfdcfox, thanks man I don't know how I missed that.. Thank you have a good day!